# How to retrieve elements from another table in a SQL query?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

> Sorry my english !!!!

I get data from a table ***wp_posts*** and now I need to get data from the table **wp_postmeta** that match the ID captured in **wp_posts** table.

The data that I need to grab in the table ***wp_postmeta*** are `product_img1`, `product_img2`, `product_img3` as shown in image below.

[image]

This is a view of my ***wp_posts***:

[image]

I need to show ***ID***, ***post_title***, ***product_img1***, ***product_img2***, ***product_img3*** and I am the SQL:

```
$show_info = $pdo("SELECT p.*, pm.*  
                   FROM wp_posts p  
                   JOIN wp_postmeta pm ON p.post_id = pm.meta_id 
                   WHERE p.post_type = 'wpcproduct'"
                 );
```

> Can you help me to show this data for ID 103?

Comment: ID, post_title (wp_posts) and product_img1, product_img2, product_img3 (wp_postmeta) ... Help me please to show this data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the correct query for you is:

```
SELECT p.*, pm.*  
FROM wp_posts p  
JOIN wp_postmeta pm ON p.ID = pm.post_id 
WHERE p.post_type = 'wpcproduct'
```

Since you want to match the `post_id` column on the `wp_postmeta` with the `ID` column on wp_posts

If you only want data from post id 103, do:

```
SELECT p.*, pm.*  
FROM wp_posts p  
JOIN wp_postmeta pm ON p.ID = pm.post_id 
WHERE p.post_type = 'wpcproduct'
AND p.ID = 103
```

If you only want to display some columns, then do the following:

```
SELECT p.ID, p.post_title, pm.product_img1, pm.product_img2, pm.product_img3 
FROM wp_posts p  
JOIN wp_postmeta pm ON p.ID = pm.post_id 
WHERE p.post_type = 'wpcproduct'
AND p.ID = 103
```

Comment: How to show in PHP the data result of the SQL please?

Comment: @MarcosVinicius see my update. (Ultimo paragrafo, acabei de atualizar)

Comment: What do you mean show in PHP? Is your problem doing the query or processing the query and displaying the results?

Comment: Processing the query and displaying the results !!!

Comment: I'm a big error because `pm.product_img1, pm.product_img2, pm.product_img3 ` isn`t columns ... Display error here: http://pastebin.com/faqKakEP

Comment: @MarcosVinicius if you are getting this errors, it means that these columns don't exist. Are you sure that's the right name? Also, are you sure they are on the wp_postmeta table? (maybe they are on the wp_posts table). If you can just add the schema of your tables it would be great. To get it, just run `DESCRIBE wp_postmeta;` and `DESCRIBE wp_posts;` and paste both results for us to see.